# How to apply indexing for expression of type int c#

Tags: c#

I have to split a value example 44 I need the second 4. I have a way to so so now I just can figure how to make int index-able. I can make it indexable using string but I need it in int. How can I solve this issue?

Conversion that does not work

```
int secondDigit = num;
ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup)Convert.ChangeType(secondDigit, typeof(ScaleGroup));

int num = Convert.ToInt32(ld.ScaleGroup);
char secondDigit = num[1];//here is the issue
```

Comment: Perhaps you need the value as an `int` later in your code, but why would you need it as an `int` to index it? Use the `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
int secondDigit = (int) char.GetNumericValue(num.ToString()[1]);
```

But a simpler option would be:

```
int secondDigit1 = num % 10;
```

If `Id.ScaleGroup` is a string then you can directly access its value at index 1, but remember to check the `Length` before accessing index.

The simpler option *(involving % division)* would only work for two digit numbers.

Comment: `num % 10` gives the last digit, which may not always be the second digit if he's got a number bigger than 99

Comment: @Habib would you happen to know how to convert int to custom type here is what i have so far I posted on edit.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos There is not enough information. What does `ScaleGroup` do?

Comment: @nmclean it just a comaprison to see if the group values match

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Do you have the source code or documentation for this class?